Simple program fails Error: memory allocation failed, out of memory, consumed 2474 of 200000 compute units
I'm trying to write a program to be able to init and mint different tokens. So I pass dynamic seed during program invocation as a parameter, but somehow running out of memory in the mint_tokens function.
pub fn mint_tokens(ctx: Context<MintTokens>, quantity: u64, seed: String) -> Result<()> {
    msg!("Starting mint_tokens function...");
    msg!("Seed: {}", seed);
    msg!("Quantity: {}", quantity);

    let seeds = &[seed.as_bytes(), &[ctx.bumps.mint]];
    let signer = &[&seeds[..]];

    msg!("Signer created, proceeding to mint...");

    let cpi_accounts = MintTo {
        authority: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
        to: ctx.accounts.destination.to_account_info(),
        mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
    };
    let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
    let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(cpi_program, cpi_accounts, signer);

    mint_to(cpi_ctx, quantity)?;

    msg!("Tokens minted successfully.");

    Ok(())
}


 #[derive(Accounts)]
 #[instruction(seed: String)]
    pub struct MintTokens<'info> {
    #[account(
            mut,
            seeds = [seed.as_bytes()],
            bump,
            mint::authority = mint,
        )]
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(
            init_if_needed,
            payer = payer,
            associated_token::mint = mint,
            associated_token::authority = payer,
        )]
    pub destination: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>     }

Init function works well with the same seed.
pub fn init_token(
    ctx: Context<InitToken>,
    metadata: InitTokenParams,
    seed: String,
) -> Result<()> {
    msg!("Initializing token with seed: {}", seed);
    msg!("Metadata: {:?}", metadata);

    let seeds = &[seed.as_bytes(), &[ctx.bumps.mint]];
    let signer = [&seeds[..]];

    let token_data: DataV2 = DataV2 {
        name: metadata.name,
        symbol: metadata.symbol,
        uri: metadata.uri,
        seller_fee_basis_points: 0,
        creators: None,
        collection: None,
        uses: None,
    };

    msg!("Creating metadata accounts...");

    let metadata_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(
        ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
        CreateMetadataAccountsV3 {
            payer: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
            update_authority: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            metadata: ctx.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),
            mint_authority: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            rent: ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
        },
        &signer,
    );

    create_metadata_accounts_v3(metadata_ctx, token_data, false, true, None)?;

    msg!("Token mint created successfully.");

    Ok(())
}

What makes my program run out of memory? How can I debug it?
Thanks!

You might need to also provide the inputs to your program. For example, if you have a very large string, it might use up all the heap space in all of the different programs.
